# How To Expand Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Filesystem Volume on Hyper-V

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, hyper-v, windows-server

I created a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS virtual machine (VM) on Hyper-V and now I am running out of disk space and I need to increase the filesystem space.

Answer (score 29):

I tried existing solutions on 18.04 and found it doesn't work with a 'nothing to do' output.  Some further searching had similar-but-slightly-different steps and needing to merge a few different bits-and-pieces from other solutions on the web to make work.

Setup: Hyper-V; VHDX file as hard disk; Ubuntu-18.04

Steps:

1. Expand the VDHX file via Hyper-V as mentioned in existing solutions and then inside the VM:
2. `fdisk -l`

   See which partition is the current Ubuntu setup - should be obvious based on size (in my case was sda3)
3. `growpart /dev/sda 3`

   Note the space as mentioned.
4. `pvresize /dev/sda3`

   This is the step which isn't mentioned in a lot of places; its the intemediate step that allows the logical volume extension step work.
5. `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv`

   The `/dev/` part can seen in the fdisk output from step 1.
6. `resize2fs  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`

   After the prep above, this step now works.  Takes a couple of moments and afterwards can verify with `df -h` that the partition is expanded.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

This is an issue I've run into so many times, I've decided to leave a public trace on how to do it quickly.

1. In Hyper-V, edit the virtual machine and go under “Hard Drive”
2. Click on “Edit”, select “Expand” and enter the desired size
3. Reboot the virtual machine
4. SSH into the virtual machine
5. Run `sudo lvdisplay` to get the name of the logical volume
6. Run `sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv` to extend the volume to the maximum size available
7. Run `df -h` to see the status of the filesystem free space
8. Grab the name of your target filesystem (typically `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`)
9. Run `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` to resize the filesystem
10. Run again `df -h` and you should now see that your volume has been extended

That’s it! Rebooting might not be a bad idea.

Comment: you can also use the gparted GUI tool to resize the ubunu partition

Comment: This answer is missing two critical steps: Before step 6, the partition holding the LVM physical volume needs to be expanded. Then, the physical volume needs to be expanded (`pvresize`). See Kelly Trinh’s answer for that.

Answer (score 13):

For me, `sudo lvdisplay` does not work and returns nothing, for some reason. `GParted` also refused to start.

So I had to find other ways. Here is what brought luck:

- Start the VM again and install Guest Utils:

```
$ sudo apt install cloud-guest-utils
```

- If not using English, override locale settings to avoid issues with non-English locales:

```
$ LC_ALL=C
```

- Expand partition into the free space:

```
$ sudo growpart /dev/sda 5
# NB: space between `partition` and `id`!
```

- Resize:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda5
# NB: *no space* between partition and id!
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me.  sudo lbdisplay returned nothing and pvresize did not work either

Comment: Best solution for me as well. This works because Ubuntu 22.04 as installed by (Windows 11) Hyper-v's "Quick create -> Ubuntu 22.04" does not use LVM. It's simply an ext4 partition so all you need are growpart and resize2fs. `cat /etc/mtab` will show what file system your / is mounted as.

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu: Extend your default LVM space](https://packetpushers.net/ubuntu-extend-your-default-lvm-space/)

Resize partition: `sudo cfdisk`

Extend PV physical volume: `pvresize /dev/sda3`

Extend logical volume: `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv`

Resize: `resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`

Answer (score 0):

Setup:
Proxmox 7
Disk model: QEMU HARDDISK
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Expand the QEMU HARDDISK file via Proxmox as per Proxmox VM disk resize steps and then inside the VM:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

See which partition is the current Ubuntu setup - should be obvious based on size (in my case was sda2)

```
$ sudo growpart /dev/sda 2
# NB: space between `partition` (/dev/sda) and `id` (2)!
```

Resize:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2
# NB: *no space* between partition and id!
```

Answer (score -1):

Expand the Hyper-v hardrive, Under the Edit in Versual hard disk section.

Make sure the checkpoints are merged and deleted while the Virtual

Machine is OFF.

Boot Ubuntu system.

Command line:

```
sudo su -
fdisk -l
growpart /dev/sda 3
pvresize /dev/sda3
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
resize2fs  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
df -h
```

Comment: How isn't this an exact duplicate of https://superuser.com/a/1748427/705502, or am I missing something?